# Plot Data by 1 second intervals efficently

Tags: r, plot

So I've already done this (inefficiently), but for future reference I'd like to know if there's a better way.

What I'm doing is plotting the number of packets, and data sent every second in a trace. Code currently is:

```
trace$sec = cut(trace$V1, breaks = seq(0, 1800, by = 1), labels = 1:1800)
packet_count_vec = numeric()
data_trans_vec = numeric()
for (i in 0:1800 ) {
  print(i)
  bin = which(trace$sec == i)
  packet_count = 0
  data_trans = 0
  for (j in bin) {
    packet_count = packet_count + 1
    data_trans = data_trans + trace[j,]$V6
  }
  packet_count_vec = c(packet_count_vec, packet_count)
  data_trans_vec = c(data_trans_vec, data_trans)
}
par(mfrow=c(2, 1))
plot(packet_count_vec, type = "l", xlab = "Time (s)", ylab = "Packets")
title("Time Series of Total Packets")
plot(data_trans_vec, type = "l", xlab = "Time (s)", ylab = "Bits")
title("Time Series of Data Transferred")
```

What I do is use `cut` to add bins for second intervals to my data, then for each bin I count the number in the bin (number of packets), and for each packet I add up the data (total is data sent that second).

The trace can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-gLFtGDqKCkZjViTmpoNkdGQTg/view?usp=sharing), the important columns are:

- V1 - The time after start for the packet to be sent.
- V6 - The amount of data sent.

My current solution is reasonably slow (I have 1800 seconds), and I'm wondering how I'd do it more efficiently next time.

Comment: Added a link to the trace!

Comment: That was left over from when I had an example instead of the file. My mistake!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I grok'd the file correctly, this is what I think you're trying to achieve. I use `read_delim` from `readr` for fast file reading, then use `dplyr` idioms to transform and summarize the data. I use `ggplot` vs base plotting and `tidyr` to transform the data again before plotting. The plotting is simplified due to the use of facets in `ggplot`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

trace <- read_delim("trace.txt", delim=" ", col_names=FALSE)
trace %>% 
  mutate(second=as.numeric(str_replace(X1, "\\..*$", ""))) %>%  # only care about the second
  group_by(second) %>%                                          # group by the second
  summarise(`Total Packets`=n(),                                # get packet count
            `Data Transferred (Bits)`=sum(X6)) -> trace         # get data count

head(trace)

## Source: local data frame [6 x 3]
## 
##   second Total Packets Data Transferred (Bits)
## 1      0           151                    5497
## 2      1           203                   11146
## 3      2           170                   13986
## 4      3           163                   10541
## 5      4           152                    6781
## 6      5           147                    9087

gg <- ggplot(gather(trace, Measure, value, -second))
gg <- gg + geom_line(aes(x=second, y=value, color=Measure))
gg <- gg + scale_y_continuous(label=comma)
gg <- gg + facet_wrap(~Measure, ncol=1, scales="free_y")
gg <- gg + labs(x="Time (s)", y=NULL)
gg <- gg + theme_bw()
gg <- gg + theme(legend.position="none")
gg
```

[image]